# Concatenate a single column into a comma delimited list

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I've seen multiple examples of people rolling up a single column into a comma delimited list, but I need a bit more.

Here is an example of the data and results I need.

```
DECLARE @SalesPerson table (SalesPersonID int, SalesPersonName varchar(10))
DECLARE @Region table (RegionID int, RegionName varchar(15))
DECLARE @SalesPersonRegion table (SalesPersonID int, RegionID int)

INSERT INTO @SalesPerson (SalesPersonID, SalesPersonName) VALUES (1,'Jeff') 
INSERT INTO @SalesPerson (SalesPersonID, SalesPersonName) VALUES (2,'Pat') 
INSERT INTO @SalesPerson (SalesPersonID, SalesPersonName) VALUES (3,'Joe') 

INSERT INTO @Region (RegionID, RegionName) VALUES (1,'North') 
INSERT INTO @Region (RegionID, RegionName) VALUES (2,'South') 
INSERT INTO @Region (RegionID, RegionName) VALUES (3,'East') 
INSERT INTO @Region (RegionID, RegionName) VALUES (4,'West') 

INSERT INTO @SalesPersonRegion (SalesPersonID,RegionID) VALUES (1,1)
INSERT INTO @SalesPersonRegion (SalesPersonID,RegionID) VALUES (1,2)
INSERT INTO @SalesPersonRegion (SalesPersonID,RegionID) VALUES (1,3)
INSERT INTO @SalesPersonRegion (SalesPersonID,RegionID) VALUES (2,2)
INSERT INTO @SalesPersonRegion (SalesPersonID,RegionID) VALUES (2,3)
INSERT INTO @SalesPersonRegion (SalesPersonID,RegionID) VALUES (2,4)
INSERT INTO @SalesPersonRegion (SalesPersonID,RegionID) VALUES (3,1)
INSERT INTO @SalesPersonRegion (SalesPersonID,RegionID) VALUES (3,4)
```

A simple select will get me each sales person, with each of that salesperson's region.

```
SELECT 
    sp.SalesPersonID,
    sp.SalesPersonName,
    r.RegionName
FROM @SalesPersonRegion spr
    JOIN @SalesPerson sp
        ON spr.SalesPersonID = sp.SalesPersonID
    JOIN @Region r
        ON spr.RegionID = r.RegionID
```

In this case, it will return 9 Rows.

I would like to get results like this:

```
SalesPersonID    SalesPersonName      Regions
1                Jeff                 North,South,East
2                Pat                  South,East,West
3                Joe                  North,West
```

Comment: Take a look at this approach: http://codecorner.galanter.net/2009/06/25/t-sql-string-aggregate-in-sql-server/

Comment: FOR XML or CONCAT

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  sp.SalesPersonID, 
  sp.SalesPersonName, 
  Regions = STUFF
  (
    (
      SELECT ',' + r.RegionName
       FROM @Region AS r
       INNER JOIN @SalesPersonRegion AS spr
       ON r.RegionID = spr.RegionID
       WHERE spr.SalesPersonID = sp.SalesPersonID
       ORDER BY r.RegionID
       FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    ).value('.[1]','nvarchar(max)'),
    1,1,''
  )
FROM @SalesPerson AS sp
ORDER BY sp.SalesPersonID;
```

Comment: It seems it can live without `, TYPE` and `.value('.[1]','nvarchar(max)')`, isn't it ?

Comment: @i-one have you tried it with a region named `Cape Cod & Islands`?

Comment: Yeah, I see `&amp;`, good point. Is it the only point or are there more potentially?

Comment: @i-one any non-XML-safe character, e.g. `>` -> `&gt;`, `<` -> `&lt;`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Try this query:

```
SELECT 
    sp.SalesPersonID,
    sp.SalesPersonName,
    reg.Regions
FROM @SalesPerson sp
    CROSS APPLY( -- or OUTER APPLY
        SELECT STUFF(
        (SELECT ','+r.RegionName
        FROM    @Region r INNER JOIN @SalesPersonRegion spr ON r.RegionID = spr.RegionID
        WHERE   spr.SalesPersonID = sp.SalesPersonID
        FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') AS Regions
    )reg;
```

Results:

```
SalesPersonID SalesPersonName Regions
------------- --------------- ----------------
1             Jeff            North,South,East
2             Pat             South,East,West
3             Joe             North,West
```

Comment: I think the cross apply and additional nested selects just complicates things needlessly.

Comment: In this case it's matter of style. Usually,  I like to find/see all source tables/views/etc. in `FROM` clause (of parent query).

Answer (score 2):

```
select
    sp.SalesPersonID,
    sp.SalesPersonName,
    stuff(
       (
           select ',' + r.RegionName
           from @SalesPersonRegion as spr 
               inner join @Region as r on r.RegionID = spr.RegionID
           where spr.SalesPersonID = sp.SalesPersonID
           for xml path(''), type
       ).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)')
       , 1, 1, '')
from @SalesPerson as sp
```

see [**sql fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/18653) example

Comment: How does this differ from my answer?

Comment: It doesn t have [1] but in general you right this one is redundant here - i've spent too much time with formatting and sql fiddling